# Go - Download file from URL with Sequence

Tags: arrays, function, go

i am trying to learn some new stuff with GoLang, and got a litlebit stuck, probaly the reason is just that i am not very good at using arrays.

So heres what i want to do:

1. Make variable.
2. Download with that variable.
3. Add ++1 for that variable
4. Download with added 1

and loop it lets say 10 times.

I am all good with points 1 and two, but little stuck with 3 & 4. :).

all the files come in .pdf, thats why i made that strconv there.

I probaly should make somekind of Loop in main, and call DownloadFile function with some array parameters in there?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    url_id := strconv.Itoa(23430815+2)
    filename := url_id+".pdf"
    fileUrl := "https://someurLid="+url_id

    if err := DownloadFile(filename, fileUrl); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fileUrl)
}


func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Read about [for loops](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1) in the Tour of Go.  The example shows how to loop with an incrementing counter.  The Effective Go document also covers [the topic](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for).

Comment: @CeriseLimón - You can post this as answer, that was the one what gave me the solution :).

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    url_id_num := 23430815+2
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        url_id := strconv.Itoa(url_id_num+i)
        filename := url_id+".pdf"
        fileUrl := "https://someurLid="+url_id

        if err := DownloadFile(filename, fileUrl); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(fileUrl)
    }
}

func DownloadFile(filepath string, url string) error {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    out, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Cerise Limón gave the answer and thats thats how it worked out.

```
    arr := make([]uint8, 3) //How many times it loops
url_id := 23430815 //Starting from id, filename
for range arr {
    filename := strconv.Itoa(url_id)+".pdf"
    fileUrl := "https://someurl?id="+strconv.Itoa(url_id)

    if err := DownloadFile(filename, fileUrl); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fileUrl)
    url_id++
}
```

Thank you for pointing out where i should start! :).